# Storing digital certificate in AWS Cloud HSM

Tags: amazon-web-services, hsm, amazon-cloudhsm

My use case is to store digital certificate (issued by some certificate authority) in AWS Cloud HSM. I know we can store private key that signs the certificate. But is it possible to store full digital certificate itself? Can someone please share the steps?

Comment: A certificate is public information.  Why would you want to store it in a HSM?

Comment: posted an answer, if it helped you consider accepting it so that it helps others in the future

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot store `digital certificate` in CloudHSM device

Here are things what you can achieve with it

When you use an HSM from AWS CloudHSM, you can perform a variety of cryptographic tasks:

- Generate, store, import, export, and manage cryptographic keys, including symmetric keys and asymmetric key pairs.
- Use symmetric and asymmetric algorithms to encrypt and decrypt data.
- Use cryptographic hash functions to compute message digests and hash-based message authentication codes (HMACs).
- Cryptographically sign data (including code signing) and verify signatures.
- Generate cryptographically secure random data.

[Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/introduction.html) & [fAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/faqs/) for more reference

Comment: can you share some links related cryptographic functions and Cryptographically signing data?

Comment: This should help 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/signing-data-using-keys-stored-in-aws-cloudhsm-with-python/
if this helped you, it would be great if you can accept this as answer, so that it can help others in the future